# Cesuim handle timebar click

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

How to handle Cesuim timebar click?
It would be very comfortable to get clicked time in callback.
Im nearly sure that it is implemented, so im looking for something like this.

```
function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.CLICKED_DATETIME);
}

viewer.timebar.ON_TIMEBAR_CLICK = handleClick;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty simple.  Here's [what Viewer does](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/010c2d41cb9da6e6c2039000c4416084e9db90b3/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer.js#L610) currently:

```
viewer.timeline.addEventListener('settime', onTimelineScrubfunction, false);
```

But, some caveats:

- This event will fire quite rapidly if the user "scrubs" (drags the current time bar across the timeline).  Be prepared for a lot of events at once, like mousemove or touch/pointer move.  Don't try to animate the globe during the event, just set some variable to take effect on the next animation frame [like Viewer does](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/010c2d41cb9da6e6c2039000c4416084e9db90b3/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer.js#L99-L103).
- This API is technically "private", which just means it is subject to change in any release without Cesium's normal deprecation policy.  Even so, it's the only way to get this event, so go ahead and use it, just be careful to retest it particularly after reading about any timeline changes in the release notes (this is uncommon, as the timeline has been static for a long time now, but someday a full replacement could happen).

Comment: Thanks, emackey. But i think second argument is enough strong to avoid using  'settime'. So what do you think about this viewer.timeline.container.onmouseup?

Answer (score 2):

not too elegant but also an option

```
viewer.timeline.container.onmouseup = (e) => {
  console.log(viewer.clock.currentTime);
}
```

Comment: This won't work for touch screens.  Also `container` is part of the timeline API, all of that API is "private" (because it's all been due for a rewrite for a long time, since before Cesium 1.0).

Comment: It will give you a single event at the end of the scrub, so that part is good.